# How to set decimal point in y-axis in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here is the reproducible dataframe.

```
variable <- c("A1","B1","C1","D1","A1","B1","C1","D1","A1","B1","C1","D1")
period <- c("P1","P1","P1","P1","P2","P2","P2","P2","P3","P3","P3","P3")

coef <- runif(12, -1, 1)
coef_lb <- coef-0.3
coef_ub <- coef+0.3

df<- data.frame(variable,period,coef,coef_lb,coef_ub)

df$period <- factor(df$period,levels=c("P1","P2","P3"))

library(ggplot2)
bpdiaplot <- ggplot(data=df,aes(x=period,y=coef))
bpdiaplot <- bpdiaplot + facet_grid(.~variable,labeller = label_parsed)
bpdiaplot <- bpdiaplot + geom_pointrange(aes(ymin=coef_lb,ymax=coef_ub))
bpdiaplot <- bpdiaplot + geom_point() 
bpdiaplot <- bpdiaplot + scale_y_continuous(limits=c(-1.4, 1.4),breaks=seq(-1.4, 1.4, by = 0.3))
bpdiaplot <- bpdiaplot + xlab("Period") 
bpdiaplot <- bpdiaplot + ylab("Mean difference") 
bpdiaplot <- bpdiaplot + geom_hline(yintercept=0,alpha=0.5)
bpdiaplot <- bpdiaplot + theme_bw()
bpdiaplot <- bpdiaplot + theme(axis.text = element_text(colour = "black"))
bpdiaplot <- bpdiaplot + theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))
```

By changing the "breaks=seq(-1.4, 1.4, by = 0.3))" into "breaks=seq(-1.4, 1.4, by = 0.1))", it returns different decimal point in y-axis.

How can I control the decimal point in y-axis? I would like to have only one decimal point.

[image: Using breaks=seq(-1.4, 1.4, by = 0.1))]

[[image: Using breaks=seq(-1.4, 1.4, by = 0.1))[2]]

Comment: I don't know why this happened (some weird floating-point thing?), but a quick fix may be `breaks=round(seq(-1.4, 1.4, by = 0.1),1)`

Comment: Thank you, it solves the problem.